# Redis race condition: `Keys *` sometimes returns incorrect amount of keys

Tags: redis, race-condition

I have 2 applications. First one is writing keys such as

```
SET MyKey_1
SET MYKey_2
```

and then sends notification to second application via network.

Other application waits for notification and then counts how many keys with specific prefix is in DB:

```
KEYS MyKey_*
```

if key count is different from expected it raises an error:

```
waitNotification(firstAppSocket)
if redisCount("KEYS MyKey_*") != 2 {
  panic("wrong key count")
}
```

Sometimes I encounter into race condition where 1-st app sets key and receives OK from Redis, notifies 2-nd app, but count returns 1. This happens approx. 1 in 10 times. If I retry count operation after a very short timeout (talking microseconds) it becomes correct.

Is there a race condition in Redis for such operation? Is there key population timeout?

Comment: what version of redis you are using? in version 5 or older, redis is still single thread so no race condition.

only in redis 6, multi thread is introduced.

can you post the code snippet so that other can chime in

Comment: `$ redis-server --version
Redis server v=5.0.7 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.2.1 bits=64 build=636cde3b5c7a3923`

Comment: KEYS mykey* is a blocking statement, it can produce some unexpected results when multiple clients are trying to access Redis while a blocked operation is underway. Try using SCAN mykey* instead and see if it fixes the problem.